# Timer not detecting when input matches DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, datetime, timer

I have a timer on my form with an interval of 1000 (1 second). I am allowing the user to input a time via three comboboxes. The time they input is then converted to the DateTime format. Finally, the timer checks every tick if the input time equals `DateTime.Now`. The problem is that it's not working.

Say I set the alarm to 9:00:00 PM when it's 8:59:50 PM. I click Start and wait ten seconds for the alarm to go off, but it never does. When debugging the code, both numbers are the same, meaning that it should fire, but it doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
private void tmrAlarm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DateTime alarmTime = Convert.ToDateTime(statusAlarm.Text); // say statusAlarm.Text is 9:00:00 PM

    if(alarmTime == DateTime.Now) {
        MessageBox.Show("bzzt");
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of accomplishing this (for example, counting seconds rather than checking if it's the right time)? Should I use a stopwatch instead?

Finally, could it be that it's failing because the timer started in the middle of a second rather than the beginning? Like if I started the timer at 1.05 seconds instead of on the second.

**EDIT:**

I changed the code to this:

```
if(alarmTime.Hour == DateTime.Now.Hour &&
   alarmTime.Minute == DateTime.Now.Minute &&
   alarmTime.Second == DateTime.Now.Second) { ... }
```

It's a little clunky-looking, but it works perfectly!

Comment: DateTime.Now includes fractional seconds. Thus `==` can't be used with it directly for useful results in this case.

Comment: You need to round off the DateTime to seconds and then compare, and use not `==` but `>`. Then it will work even if you don't round off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that `DateTime.Now` returns a very precise value, with fractional seconds. Therefore, you will most likely never hit the  point where the `==` condition would be met.

To do what you want, you must take only the 'higher level' values of the returned DateTime (h,m, s).

Comment: I've just changed the code to check h/m/s and it works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I will once I can accept it. Just have to wait a minute... Edit: Accepted! Thanks again!

Comment: This does not work in all cases. A time could be skipped, due to a daylight saving time adjustment, the clock being set manually, or the machine being in a sleep state, or the check might not be fired for over a second, etc. due to poor performance of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

`DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()` method for checking equality

Answer (score 0):

You can't depend on the timer being fired at exactly the target time (as suggested by other answers), regardless of the granularity.
(Also, comparing rounded times can cause the event to fire early, if it is not already a round value).

If you round to a second, it could be missed if the machine was running very slowly due to another process hogging processor time.
If you round to a larger interval (even hours or days), it could still be missed if the machine was in sleep/hibernate mode at the time, or that time could actually be skipped due to a daylight saving time adjustment.

A correct way to test if the time of an event has been reached is to check for the current time being greater than or equal to the target time.
You would have to disable the timer or flag that the event was fired, so that it doesn't fire it again.

You might not want to fire missed events (e.g. if the machine was off at the target time, the action might or might not be desirable when it is next turned on). In that case, you have to test for the current time being between the target time (inclusive) and the target time plus a certain interval (the maximum time interval after the target time at which you would still want to fire the event).